# Use Winsock insde DShow Filter

Tags: directshow, winsock

I am trying to develop a DirectShow filter with internet access.

When I try to use Winsock,

1) In TCP, I wait connections but cannot access to server (try with Telnet) and

2) In UDP in data wait step (recvfrom(...)) program breaks.

Is it not possible? Or do I have to change library settings for the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you remember to call WSAStartup before creating sockets?

Also do you check your return values from calls such as "socket"?  Its definitely not returning an INVALID_SOCKET?

Comment: Yes, I call WSAstartup and int returns non zero, and yes socket() does not return INVALID_SOCKET

Comment: When you say it "breaks" how exactly does it break?  Does it give any errors in the output window?

Comment: Well, if I debug the program, the debug ends at the specified line without an output.

Comment: Any chance of an update to your question with some code?  Cos i've had no troubles using winsock from a DShow filter ...